# Stuck in a unit test

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce

I'm new in salesforce and I'm learning unit test. Can someone help me to solve my problem?
I'm writing unit test for my CountCasesOfContact class but it's failing. What should I change? Here is my class and unit test code:

```
public class CountCasesOfContact {
    private List<Case> caseList;
    private List<Case> oldList;

    public static void countCases(List<Case> caseList, List<Case> oldList){

        Map<Id, Contact> contactsToUpdate = new Map<Id, Contact>();

        //Run the trigger for all after events, check if object has trigger.new and/or trigger.old and collect parent object and it's id in a map
        if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.new != null){
                for(Case cs: caseList) {
                    contactsToUpdate.put(cs.ContactId, new Contact(Id=cs.ContactId,Open_Cases_Count__c=0, Closed_Cases_Count__c = 0));
                }
        }
        if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.old != null) {
            for(Case cs: oldList) {
                contactsToUpdate.put(cs.ContactId, new Contact(Id=cs.ContactId,Open_Cases_Count__c=0, Closed_Cases_Count__c = 0));
            }
        }

        //remove null id-contact pairs from map
        contactsToUpdate.remove(null); 
        
        //Get count result of open/closed Cases for each contact and set the value to related fields
        for(AggregateResult result: [SELECT COUNT(Id) caseCount, ContactId ContactId FROM Case WHERE Status = 'Closed' AND ContactId = :contactsToUpdate.keySet() GROUP BY ContactId] ) {
            contactsToUpdate.get((Id)result.get('ContactId')).Closed_Cases_Count__c=(Integer)result.get('caseCount');
        }
        for(AggregateResult result: [SELECT COUNT(Id) caseCount, ContactId ContactId FROM Case WHERE Status != 'Closed' AND ContactId = :contactsToUpdate.keySet() GROUP BY ContactId] ) {
            contactsToUpdate.get((Id)result.get('ContactId')).Open_Cases_Count__c=(Integer)result.get('caseCount');
        }
        update contactsToUpdate.values();
    }
}
```

and test for it:

```
@isTest
public class CountCasesOfContactTest {
@isTest
    private static void countCasesTestInsert(){
        
        Test.startTest();
        Contact ct = new Contact(LastName = 'Test Contact', Open_Cases_Count__c = 0, Closed_Cases_Count__c = 0);
        insert ct;

        Case cs = new Case(ContactId = ct.id, Subject = 'Test Case', Status = 'New', Origin = 'Phone');
        insert cs;
        
        CountCasesOfContact.countCases([Select id From Case], null);
        Test.stopTest();

        Contact cnt = [SELECT id, Open_Cases_Count__c, Closed_Cases_Count__c FROM Contact];
        system.assertEquals(1, cnt.Open_Cases_Count__c);
        system.assertEquals(0, cnt.Closed_Cases_Count__c);
    }
}
```

Waiting for pass at least for insert event but unfortunately.

Comment: Can you share more details, like the error message you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks decent, congrats, good effort.

Is your class actually hooked up to Case trigger? Do you have something like this (written just here in editor, no promises it compiles)

```apex
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (after insert, after update, after delete){
    CountCasesOfContact.countCases(trigger.new, trigger.old);
}
```

I suspect it's not hooked up. Which would be fine, you could still call it in the test as `CountCasesOfContact.countCases([Select id From Case], null);` ... but you don't really use what you passed! `if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.new != null)` doesn't meet the conditions here if you're not inside a trigger context. You don't loop over `caseList`.

I'd convert it to some `if(caseList != null && !caseList.isEmpty())`. That way you have freedom to both pass `trigger.new` to it and make it work as well as pass just a list of Cases and reuse this code as some data fix for existing data.

So... fix the ifs. And then

- either hook it up to actual trigger
- or change the query in the test to `[Select Id, ContactId From Case]`. Because the moment you fix the ifs it'll start to throw "SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: ContactId"

Comment: Hi eyescream,
Thank you for help.
I downloaded and used pre-defined TriggerHandler class with its methods and extended it to my CaseTriggerHandler class, all events are defined there with override. There, I found that I called my CountCasesOfContact.countCases(caseList, null) method without my class name.  :) ....So, you were right, I forgot call the class.  Now it is working. Thank you!

Comment: Trigger of Case is like:

trigger CaseTrigger on Case (before insert, before update) {
    new CaseTriggerHandler().run();
  }

Comment: glad I could help. mark my answer accepted pls so it drops off the list of unanswered questions? or post your own answer and accept that, I'd happily upvote and you'd get some karma points. https://github.com/kevinohara80/sfdc-trigger-framework ? I like that one too, there are few other notable frameworks but this one is very "no nonsense"